# Arduino multiple variables in string

Tags: arduino

I am trying to get a string containing the uptime of my Arduino. I'm using this code:

```
long t = millis() / 1000;
word h = t / 3600;
byte m = (t / 60) % 60;
byte s = t % 60;
String uptime =  h/10 + h%10 + m/10 + m%10 + s/10 + s%10;
```

But I get 'invalid conversion' errors. Should I do this with sprintf or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are forced to use c: yes sprintf or much better snprintf is the right way to go for you. If you are using c++ and the STL is available you should use std::string ( but I am not sure if this is there ).

With best regards,
Kim Kulling

Answer (score 0):

Its type cast operation needed . How you could expect work. one is integer , byte and reading in string format.